# Shift particular range of elements in list

Tags: python, data-structures

I want to do something like this:

```
myList[n]. Shift myList[k:l] to the left by s.
```

**Example**: Let n be 5, s = 1 and k and l be the 3rd and 4th element in the list.

Before:

```
[a,a,b,b,a]
```

After:

```
[a,b,b,a,a]
```

To be clear: I don't want to loose 'b' items in my list, 'a' can be overwritten.

What would be the most time and space efficient way to achieve this in Python?

**Edit: NO ROTATION!**

Comment: Your example is not very clear. You could just as well have used "before: `[a,a,a,a,a]`, after: `[a,a,a,a,a]`"...

Comment: The problem with your example is that it is not clear which a/b in 'before' maps to which a/b in 'after'. The same 'after' result could have been achieved with a shift, a rotation, or even by mirroring the list. My example was not meant to be a better example, but for exemplifying the problem with your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list slice:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> s, k, l = 1, 2, 4 # 4 = 3 + 1
>>> x = lst[k:l]
>>> del lst[k:l]
>>> lst[k-s:k-s] = x
>>> lst
[1, 3, 4, 2, 5]
```

Comment: Did I spot a typo? :)

Comment: @AchmedDurangi, Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: @AchmedDurangi, That is not a typo. `lst[k-s:k-s] = x` was used to insert items at the position `k-s` (1).

Comment: I'm implementing it now.

Comment: Wouldn't have [k-s] sufficed?

Comment: @AchmedDurangi, Try `lst[k-s] = x`. It will not give you what you want; it will insert a list.

Comment: You are right, it would create a tuple if using only one delimiter. I'm giving you the answer in case my vote count goes up otherwise I will kill this flame thread.

Comment: @AchmedDurangi, a tuple (`(1, 2, 3)`) is different from a list (`[1, 2, 3]`). BTW, I updated the answer to make it clear that you want shift. How about change the example in the question?